# Prove that $\frac{\sin^3\frac{x}{2}-\cos^3\frac{x}{2}}{2+\sin x}=\frac{\cos x}{3}$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $\frac{\sin^3\frac{x}{2}-\cos^3\frac{x}{2}}{2+\sin x}=\frac{\cos x}{3}$
My Attempt:
$LHS=\frac{\sin^3\frac{x}{2}-\cos^3\frac{x}{2}}{2+\sin x}=\frac{(\sin\frac{x}{2}-\cos\frac{x}{2})(\sin^2\frac{x}{2}+\cos^2\frac{x}{2}+\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2})}{2+2\sin \frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{\sin\frac{x}{2}-\cos\frac{x}{2}}{2}$
$RHS=\frac{\cos x}{3}=\frac{\cos^2\frac{x}{2}-\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{3}$
But my LHS and RHS are not equal.Please help me.

Comment: You have made a mistake in the third $=$. Please check that part, and whether you can cancel $1 + \sin x$.

Answer (score 2):

You have correctly proved they are not equal.
[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7B(Sin%5Bx%2F2%5D%5E3%20-%20Cos%5Bx%2F2%5D%5E3)%2F(2%20%2B%20Sin%5Bx%5D),%20Cos%5Bx%5D%2F3%7D,%20%7Bx,%200,%202%20Pi%7D%5D) agrees with you.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\sin^3(0/2)-\cos^3(0/2)}{2+\sin0}=-\frac{1}{2}\neq\frac{1}{3}=\frac{\cos0}{3}$$